# How to get realtime location with Traccar API?

Tags: android, api, location, real-time, retrofit2

We're trying to get realtime updates of the devices location, by using Traccar API with Retrofit2, until now, we've only been able to get the location when the application starts (Android application).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get live updates you should be using WebSocket connection to Traccar server. Retrofit doesn't support anything like that, so you should use OkHttp directly:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(retrofit.baseUrl().url().toString() + "api/socket").build();
webSocket = WebSocketCall.create(client, request);
webSocket.enqueue(new WebSocketListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(IOException e, Response response) {
        reconnectWebSocket();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ResponseBody message) throws IOException {
        final String data = message.string();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    handleMessage(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.w(MainFragment.class.getSimpleName(), e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPong(Buffer payload) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
        reconnectWebSocket();
    }
});
```

For more information you can check official Traccar Manager app (native version):

https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-manager-android/tree/native

Answer (score -1):

@**Cesar gutierrez** I solved that problem. Real-time location and show known address using Geocoding